# Ada's private types visibility in implementation

Tags: types, visibility, private, ada, gnat

Is a private type visible in the unit's implementation? For example, the .ads:

```
package Unlimited_Strings is
   type String_Block is private;
(...)
private
   Max_Block_Size : constant Integer := 10;
   subtype String_Size_Subtype is Integer range 0..Max_Block_Size;
   type String_Block(Size : String_Size_Subtype := Max_Block_Size) is record
      Next : Unlimited_String := null;        
      Str : String(1..Size) := (others => ' ');
   end record;
```

and the .adb:

```
Aux_Ptr := new String_Block(Max_Block_Size);
```

yield a compilation error: "constraint no allowed when type has a constrained partial view".

Comment: We need an [mcve] - especially note the “complete”! because my attempt to reproduce your problem compiled perfectly.

Comment: @SimonWright, did you compile in Windows or Linux? I think this example compiles in Windows, but not in Linux. I'm using gnat 4.6 on Linux.

Comment: Your example doesn’t compile at all _because it is not complete_. (And, for info, I was on OS X).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Simon said, we need a reproducer here. I suspect the ".adb" file is not really the one corresponding to the .ads you are showing.

Note that since you are using a default value for the discriminant, you are in effect not creating an unconstrained type. That means that the compiler will always allocate the maximal size for a `String_Block` (corresponding to a `Max_Block_Size`), even when you specify a much smaller value for `Size`. This might not be what you intended (this is a tricky area).

On the other hand, since the public declaration for `String_Block` specifies that the type is constrained, you do have to specify the default value of course. Perhaps you meant:

```
   type String_Block (<>) is private;
private
   type String_Block (Size : String_Size_Subtype) is record ...
```

Again: your code is valid as far as we can tell, the above is just a suggestion on what might be better memory usage.

Comment: manuBriot, the .ads and .adb are in fact from the same unit. I think that the default value for the discriminant works, since if I don't use any it gets the default value and if I indicate a smaller value it is allocated with a smaller size. If I use `(<>)` as you indicate the error disappears.

Comment: No, that's my point. If you indicate a smaller value for the discriminant, the compiler still allocates the maximal size!

Comment: I completed the definition of the record in the question. The way I ascertained allocation size was with `Str'Last`. If I use a parameter of 5, the last index is 5, not 10. Do you mean that the compiler allocated 10 characters, but set the last index to 5?

Comment: Allocates size for 5 (you can never use index 6), but adds some padding at the end of the record so that it has the same size as if 10 was specified.